# Can someone please explain what (:+) is in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can someone please explain what (:+) is in Ruby? I have tried googling it & looking a reference guides and cant find anything. Thanks, sorry Im pretty new to Ruby & programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colon `:` before a sequence of characters* is a `Symbol` literal. This applies to `:+`, which is a `Symbol` with content "+".

A symbol can be used to reference a method with the same name in some contexts, and in a couple of places your example `:+` can be a reference to the `+` operator, which is really just a method with the same name. Ruby supports syntax to call it when it sees a plain `+` in an expression, or in some core methods it will convert `:+`

As an example you can use `:+` as shorthand to create a sum of an `Array` of integers:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject( :+ )
 => 10
```

This works because Ruby has special-cased that specific use of operators in `Array#inject` (actually defined in `Enumberable#inject`, and `Array` gets it from that module).

A more general use-case for a symbol like this is the `send` method:

```
2.send( :+, 2 )
=> 4
```

Although `2.send( "+", 2 )` works just fine too. It might seem odd when used like this instead of just `2 + 2`, but it can be handy if you want to make a more dynamic choice of operator.

---

`*` The rules for the syntax allowed or not allowed in a `Symbol` literal are a little arcane. They enable you to write shorter literals where possible, but Ruby has to avoid some ambiguous syntax such as a `Symbol` with a `.` or whitespace in the middle. This is allowed, just you have to add quotes if you generate such a `Symbol` e.g. `:"this.that"`

Comment: As a note `#inject` is actually an `Enumerable` method `Enumberable#inject` other than that great answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks Neil, that was an awesome explanation, really appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to qualify "special" a little bit. `:$set`, `:@name`, and `:'where is pancakes house?'` are all symbols but some might call those special characters.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes, but I cannot find a reference - neither the Ruby core docs on literals nor on Symbols have anything other than a couple of illustrative examples, and no link to what is allowed or not. It is also complex - `:a+b` is not allowed for example. This is probably good subject for another question, where is definitive grammar?

Comment: The definitive grammar is in [`parse.y` in MRI](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) :) Precise documentation for Ruby is very thin so questions like this unfortunately end up as variations on "what does MRI do?".

Answer (score 3):

Ruby will tell you

```
:+.class
# Symbol
```

`(:+)` is the symbol in parentheses.